# IntelliSense autocompletes #include path but shows "cannot open source file" error

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I want to get autocomplete for code from files in include paths. I added an include path to `c_cpp_properties.json` but it only made it so paths are autocompleted when writing #include. It shows "cannot open source file" errors and doesn't autocomplete the code from include paths. This is my `c_cpp_properties.json` file

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/src/**",
            ],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x86"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Also I don't know if it matters but I am using windows subsystem for linux.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that visual studio code was open in windows not wsl.